# Query multiple elements as snapshot with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve multiple elements in a single query which represent the state at the time of the query, so I can process them.

So I first tried once() first

```
 ref.orderByChild("id").startAt(100).once("child_added", function(snapshot))
```

but this just returned the first entry.
I get all the result if use on() instead of once(), but how can I then detect that all initial results have been sent to call off() to start processing my results?

I also thought of using once("value") but then I would receive all elements and would have to do the filtering on the client side, so this solution would not really scale.

So what would you propose?

Comment: Quick first answer below. You're probably looking for more, but it's hard to make that out from your description. It would really help if you edit your question to include the minimal **complete** code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all elements matching the query with a `value` listener:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("id").startAt(100);
query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.key(), childSnapshot.val());
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer and sorry if my example was not explanatory enough - this is exactly what I was looking for. As said before, I was also experimenting with a value listener, but was somehow not able to make it working!